# "Invisible Files" That Cannot Be Found Using Python For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, subprocess

I'm trying to search through all the file in all sub-directories of my root directory to output lines that contain "key_phrases" that the user input. My current code can find and output lines for most files in my sub directories, but I cannot seem to find lines in certain files of the folder, almost as if they are invisible to the search. Below is my code for the python function and Tkinter GUI for the user to input the directory and key phrases. The Tkinter GUI is just for reference, I believe the problem is in the for loop of my Python function.

## My Python Function

```
    import os


def searchandOutput(rootdir, keyPhrases):

    path = rootdir # Enter the root directory you want to search from

    key_phrases = [keyPhrases] # Enter here the key phrases in the lines you hope to find 
    key_phrases = [i.replace('\n','') for i in key_phrases] #In case an "\n" is added to the end of the string when the parameter is passed to the function

    # This for loop allows all sub directories and files to be searched
    for (path, subdirs, files) in os.walk(path): 
        files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt') or f.endswith('.log')] # Specify here the format of files you hope to search from (ex: ".txt" or ".log")
        #files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.txt') or f.endswith('.log')]
        files.sort() # file is sorted list

        files = [os.path.join(path, name) for name in files] # Joins the path and the name, so the files can be opened and scanned by the open() function

        # The following for loop searches all files with the selected format
        for filename in files:

                # Opens the individual files and to read their lines
                with open(filename) as f:
                    f = f.readlines()

                # The following loop scans for the key phrases entered by the user in every line of the files searched, and stores the lines that match into the "important" array
                for line in f:
                    for phrase in key_phrases: 
                        if phrase in line:
                            print(line)
                            break 

    print("The end of the directory has been reached, if no lines are printed then that means the key phrase does not exist in the root directory you entered.")
```

## My TKinter GUI

```
from searchandOutput import searchandOutput 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class Feedback:

    def __init__(self, master):

        master.title('Search and Output')
        master.resizable(False, False)
        master.configure(background = '#ffffff')

        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure('TFrame', background = '#ffffff')
        self.style.configure('TButton', background = '#ffffff')
        self.style.configure('TLabel', background = '#ffffff', font = ('Arial', 11))

        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, wraplength = 300, text = "Output the desired lines from the logs in the directory by entering the following.").grid(row = 0, column = 1) 

        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_content.pack()

        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Root Directory:').grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 4)
        #ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Applicable File Types:').grid(row = 1, column = 0)          
        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Key Phrase:').grid(row = 2, column = 0) 

        self.entry_rootdirectory = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width = 35, font = ('Arial', 10))
        self.text_keyphrase = Text(self.frame_content, width = 35, height = 5, font = ('Arial', 10))
        #self.text_filetypes = Text(self.frame_content, width = 35, height = 5, font = ('Arial', 10))

        self.entry_rootdirectory.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        #self.text_filetypes.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.text_keyphrase.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = 'Submit', command = self.submit).grid(row = 5, column = 0, pady = 5)
        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = 'Clear', command = self.clear).grid(row = 5, column = 1, pady = 5)




    def submit(self):
        #Enter code that connects to the python script here
        rootd = self.entry_rootdirectory.get()
        keyp = self.text_keyphrase.get(1.0, 'end')
        searchandOutput(rootd, keyp)
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Search Requested", message = "Search Completed!")


    def clear(self):
        self.entry_rootdirectory.delete(0, 'end')
        #self.text_filetypes.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.text_keyphrase.delete(1.0, 'end') 

def main():

    root = Tk()
    feedback = Feedback(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: What does "cannot seem to find lines" mean? Do you get an exception? If so, give us the traceback, and a sample file that produces that traceback. Or does the search just never match even though you're sure it should? If so, give us a sample file that should match but doesn't. And so on. More generally, see [mcve] in the help for what's needed to make your question answerable.

Comment: But let me take a wild guess anyway: You're on Windows, and you have some files that are in either UTF-16 or an OEM charset like CP1252. You open the files in Notepad, and it opens them as UTF-16 and shows you the strings you're searching for. But your Python code opens them as your default encoding (that's what `open(filename)` does), maybe UTF-8, so instead of seeing, e.g., `'abc'`, it sees `'a\0b\0c\0'`, which doesn't match `'abc'`.

Comment: Did you mean _invisible_?

Comment: My wild guess:  you've got symlinks in the tree (`followlinks=False` is default in `os.walk`)

Comment: Hi Abarnert, thank you for the response. I do get an exception with some files. Your guess is really interesting, is there a way to open and read files properly to match the input by the user? Hi Bryan, thanks for the question, sorry I spelled it wrong, and I do mean invisible.

Comment: Hi Wim, thanks for your response. I'm not too sure what that means, what should I do to try that out and see if it works?